# what are the limitations of Google's official Android port for Pi3?

Tags: pi-3, android, media, games, android-things

I wonder what the limitations of [Google's official Android port for Raspberry Pi 3](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi.html) are? Is this for end users who wish to use Android?

> Google's Android source repository gets a new device tree especially
>   for the Pi 3.

With a search engine I don't find use cases for this.

Comment: AFAICT it isn't very popular, probably because if you want an Android TV box (what the pi most resembles), you would be better off buying one of those instead.  I guess the use-case is for when people want to combine it with something involving the GPIOs, but I do not know what the state of things there is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has ported **Android Things** to the Raspberry Pi. Differences to regular Android are

- support for I2C , PWM and other interfaces
- no Android-style multitasking , a single headed or headless foreground app
- no staus bar , no menu , no home screen , no notifications
- no Play Store + infrastructure (currently deployment is over adb only !)
- less focus on Multimedia (video/3D acceleration is still unstable)

The target is not people looking for a cheap Android box. It is for developers and OEMs which want to create
medium-to-high powered IoT (Internet of Things) devices.